# How to keep http network alive when the app go into background?

Tags: ios

How to keep http network alive when the app go into background? I have tried some method to do for this ,such as I used VOIP ,but when the app goes into background ,it just runs for 3 mins maybe more less.I need send a request once a min.My method is not useful ,so what should I do ?

Comment: You might want to use background mode for doing all your things in background, for VOIP feature you may wish to use apple's callkit framework.

Comment: I had added VOIP, but the console will not print the results every time ,it only prints results for a few minutes.Then it will stop it .I am not sure my method is useful or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep the network alive without a valid reason or apple will reject your app.

iOS offers several background modes that are allowed to keep the app alive, you have to enable this on the Capabilities -> Background Modes in your app target configuration.

If you do enable Voice over IP you shouldn't have an issue keeping it alive, but your app actually has to be doing that since apple is very strict about this.

Comment: Please ignore this question that apple will reject my App,due to I used apple account is Corporate account.I am not sure my method is useful or not ,because the Xcode console will not print the request results for a long time ,when it prints a few minutes ,it will stop printing.So I am not sure it is useful or not.